# Using cryptography with ObjectMapper

Tags: ios, json, swift, objectmapper

I have a class which it is being mapped with `ObjectMapper`. In the past the mapping worked fine, but a change in the project Architecture made the webservice return fields that were `Double` to a `String` with Cryptographed value.

is it possible to decryptograph and cast the webservice field into my class variable during the mapping?

This is what I have today:

```
class PosicaoConsolidada: Mappable {
    var portifolioBalance: Double!
    var families: [Family]!

    required init?(map: Map) {}

    public func mapping(map: Map) {
        portifolioBalance <- map["pointsBalance"]
        families <- map["fam"]
    }
}
```

This is what I imagine to do:

```
class PosicaoConsolidada: Mappable {
    var portifolioBalance: Double!
    var families: [Family]!

    required init?(map: Map) {}

    public func mapping(map: Map) {
        portifolioBalance <- Double(Decryptor.decrypt(map["pointsBalance"]))
        families <- map["fam"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you tried running your code ? Here's the source for the `<-` operator in OM: https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/blob/master/Sources/Operators.swift

Comment: Actually, my code doesn't work... it says I can`t convert type Double to expected type Map

Comment: It is possible depending on what your method returns. Post the relevant code (`Decryptor.decrypt`'s declaration at least). `<-` expects Map

Comment: You could also use a custom transformation (`TransformType`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish the data decryption. ObjectMapper provides the protocol `TransformType` to deal with data transformations while mapping ([reference](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#custom-transforms)).

Transformer:

```
import ObjectMapper

class PointsTransform: TransformType {
    typealias Object = Double
    typealias JSON = String

    func transformFromJSON(_ value: Any?) -> Object? {
        guard let encoded = value as? String
            else { return nil }

        // TODO: Replace with decoding logic
        return 239_584.938
    }

    func transformToJSON(_ value: Object?) -> JSON? {
        guard let decoded = value
            else { return nil }

        return "\(decoded)"
    }
}
```

Model:

```
class PosicaoConsolidada: Mappable {
    var portifolioBalance: Double!
    var families: [Family]!

    required init?(map: Map) {}

    public func mapping(map: Map) {
        portifolioBalance <- (map["pointsBalance"], PointsTransform())
        families <- map["fam"]
    }

}
```